# retrieve next 15 mysql fields even if their ID's aren't sequential

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

I wasn't sure how to title this question because it is kind of difficult to understand;

I have a database table that stores blog posts and I am using AJAX to create an infinite scroll of those blog posts on a page. Initially, when visiting the page the 10 most recent blogs are shown.

I am using `$start` and `$limit` variables for the MySQL query so it knows which blog to start grabbing from and then how many to grab from the database. My problem is because of deleting blogs my ID's arent in sequential order so I cannot just do a standard `SELECT * FROM blogs ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit`.

Right now I am doing `SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE blog_id <= $start ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT $limit` which returns all the blogs but it creates an infinite loop for the last blog in the database. If I remove the `=` from `<=` then it will not have an infinite loop, but it skips the most recent blog.

How can I go about getting ALL the blogs from the database with a `$start` and `$limit` clause in the SQL statement, including the most recent one, without causing an infinite loop?

**EDIT:** Here is the JavaScript code executing the query:

```
var loading = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var h = $('.post-container').height();
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(st >= 0.6*h && !loading && h > 400){
        loading = true;
        $('#ajaxLoader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/blog.process.php?lastid=" + $(".post:last").attr("id"),
            success: function(html){
                if(html){
                    $(".post-container").append(html);
                    $('div#ajaxLoader').hide();
                }else{
                    $('div#ajaxLoader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                }
                loading = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT x2:**

If I switch the `$start` and `$limit` variables like this `LIMIT $limit,$start` then I start getting results, but they are the oldest results... I want the most recent results by grabbing the ID's in descending order

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the `LIMIT $start, $limit` approach is not working for you.  Just because there maybe be gaps in blog_id because of deletions, doesn't mean that the blog_id are not in order if the field is created via an autoincrement.

Comment: I'm a little confused about this. There's no looping construct in your query, so there should be no way for sql to enter an "infinite loop." And, as codingbiz says, non-sequential IDs should not be a problem either.

Comment: I don't know why the `LIMIT $start, $limit` approach isn't working either. It never has for me when trying this query with non-sequential ID's. The looping construct ISN'T displayed. That is in my JavaScript for the Infinite Scroll. When the user reaches the bottom of the page, that query is executed. If it is `<=` The `=` sign continues to display the last blog ID (in descending order) over and over again.

Comment: I think we do not need to your javascript code , just create a http://sqlfiddle.com link and show us `infinite` loop with your select query

Comment: The infinite loop is NOT in the query. The query is being called infinite amount of times because of the infinite scroll, but it is repeating the last entry infinite amount of times because of the `=` sign.

Answer (score 0):

If analytic functions are available in MySQL then you may use `ROW_NUMBER()` to sequence the rows with non-sequential id's. Then use row number in your where clause.

This is general example of using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT empno, deptno, ename, sal
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ename) Row_Seq 
FROM scott.emp
)
WHERE row_seq BETWEEN 1 AND 3
/

EMPNO    DEPTNO    ENAME    SAL    ROW_NUM
--------------------------------------------
7876    20    ADAMS    1100        1
7499    30    ALLEN    1600        2
7698    30    BLAKE    2850        3
```

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't able to figure out the reason why `LIMIT $start, $limit` wasn't working, but I was able to solve this problem by using this function:

```
public function getLastBlogId() {
    $sql = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM blogs ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 1");

    $row = $sql->fetch_assoc();

    $num = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string(intval($row['blog_id']));
    $num = $num + 1;
    return $num;
}
```

to get the highest blog ID in the table then add +1 to it so I don't have to use `<=` in the query. The `=` sign was the part causing the infinite loop, and I needed it to include the most recent blog. So adding +1 to the highest blog ID will get every blog below that ID, which is all the blogs.